# Why is it showing "Expected expression" when I try to write percentages?

Tags: python

This is practice code of making an invoice containing different commodities where GST is different for each one of the 4 types of pricing of products.

```
product = input('name product')
price = input('give price')

if product == 'footwear':
    if price <= 500:
        x = 5%        

if (product == 'footwear'):
    if price > 500:
        x = 18% 

if product == 'apparels':
    if price <= 1000:
        x = 5%           

if product == 'apparels':        
    if price <= 1000:
        x = 12%         
        
print('item:', product)
print('price:', price)
print('GST:', price * x)
print('total:', (price * x) + price)
```

I am just learning, but I don't know why it is showing "Expected expression".

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to StackOverflow! Just a friendly tip, try to make your question a bit clearer, (that way we will be able to better help you) its kind of confusing right now see also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

When you write `5%`, you are actually using the mod operator which needs a second parameter.

The operator `%` will return the remainder of the division between 2 numbers. Thus `6%3` will return 0, `7%3` will return 1, `8%3` will return 2, etc.

To save the actual percentage, you can use decimal numbers, like for 5%: `0.05`.

Comment: @GijoShow check which way around your `>=`/`<` are

Comment: @GijoShow if none of the conditions are met, the variable `x` won't exist. You should assign a default value or use else in all conditions